# Prevent workbook save when cell is NOT empty

Tags: excel, vba

I need to prevent excel from saving when certain cells are filled, ie. have data in them.

I have found tons of guides to prevent it from saving when cells are empty, so got the form covered, however I cannot figure out how to prevent it from saving when it is NOT empty.
Anyone?

Comment: take those guides and follow them.  where they make the boolean check to proceed, use NOT to change the result.  ie if the command was `WHILE VARIABLE =FALSE DO' change it to `WHILE NOT(VARIABLE=FALSE) DO`.  The not will mean you need to opposite condition to be TRUE.  There may be some loop whole here and there to the logic check, but without some example code its hard to say where change needs to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo example that uses cell **B9** on sheet `Sheet1`.  In the workbook code area install:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim CellToCheck As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set CellToCheck = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9")
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    If wf.CountBlank(CellToCheck) = 1 Then
        Cancel = False
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Please clear Sheet1 cell B9"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Modify this to reference your specific cells and sheets.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    'If cell Sheet 1 A1 is empty save
    If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```